# Storing ampersand in database

Tags: sql-server

I am currently working with an sql 2008 database.
Many of the entries have ampersands stored thusly 'Arts & Culture'
Should we be storing the escaped version in the database?
Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking, everything in a database should be stored as close to original version as possible. If you have to do any escaping, do it outside the DB.

Reason for doing so is simple: it's only in web where you have to esape the `&` sign. If you will sometime have a non-web front-end to your DB, you will have to convert these escape sequences back to original value, which is not always possible: for example, if a user will enter `&amp;` (sic), upon reconversion this will be translated back to `&`, which will lose original meaning.

Comment: Thanks, I guess whoever set this up saved as is from the web ui and that is why there are these escaped characters everywhere. I will need to do a search and replace I guess.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server will store `Arts & Culture` just fine, into either a VARCHAR(x) or a NVARCHAR(x) (Unicode-variant - 2 bytes per character) field.

From a database point of view, there's absolutely no need or no point in escaping anything.