# PHP/MySQL - form input value "&" get saved as "&amp;"

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8

I use CodeIgniter and I have a formula with some input fields. The problem is that when I write special characters into the input fields like "&" it gets saved as `&amp;` and when I reload the form to edit the value it is shown like this.
This leads to many errors and needs to be solved. The value needs to saved as "&".

I use form_validation for the input fields like that:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("input1", "Name", "required|trim");
$this->form_validation->set_rules("input2", "Name", "required|trim");
```

Later, I write all inputs in an array and hand it over to a function in the model:

```
$input= array();
$input["input1"] = set_value("input1");
$input["input2"] = set_value("input2");
$this->MInput->update_input($input_id, $input);
```

The model looks like this:

```
function update_input($input_id, $input) {
    if($this->db->update("pa_it_input", $input, "id = $input_id") === FALSE) {
        $error = $this->db->error();
        log_message("error", "Database error in MInput [".$error["code"]."] ".$error["message"]);
        return FALSE;
    }
```

I do not know what caused the error. I have already checked that all tables are set to UTF-8 and also the pages load in UTF-8.

Comment: So what does the documentation for the interface that you are passing strings to & from say about characaters & strings like `&` & `&amp;`? Please also read & act on [mcve].

Comment: This is similar to the ff link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704233/the-best-way-to-store-ampersand-in-mysql-database AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545735/storing-ampersand-in-database

Comment: Will probably be related to your form. Please show it. Use formhelpers or `form_prep()`

Answer (score 0):

Is this involving PHP?  What version of PHP?  Does it have "magic quotes" turned on?

Is there any code calling `htmlentities()`?

`&` -> `&amp;` is an "HTML Entity" issue, not a "UTF-8" issue.

What is CodeIgniter bringing to the table?  Perhaps some gratuitous changes like this?  It is a mistake to assume that the only use for the incoming 'form' text is to put it out in HTML.  In your case it is going into MySQL, which needs a *different* escaping mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter converts special characters to html entities. It has some security concerns to do that. To solve your problem php's `htmlspecialchars_decode()` function will help.

If your formula saved in the database have `&amp;` then decode your content before passing it to the Model.

```
$input= array();
$input["input1"] = htmlspecialchars_decode(set_value("input1"));
$input["input2"] = htmlspecialchars_decode(set_value("input2"));
$this->MInput->update_input($input_id, $input);
```

This will save '&' instead of `'&amp;'` but if your database have correct content with '&' and its just not displaying '&' correctly in your edit form. Then you need to use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` function at your HTML page where input value is set.

```
<input type="text" name="input1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($formula_val); ?>" />
```